# IIS 7.5 and asp.net ; How secure the login page

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7.5

I would like to apply a basic 2nd level of security by adding some form of web folder password protection, so that we only allow users with the global username and password to be able to access the logon page, where we are using forms based authentication.
I am not sure whether this is done from the IIS Manager (Windows 7) or by editing a web.config file ?

Comment: Yes, have been looking all day, so I thought I'd try this forum

Answer (score 0):

If you google for "Forms Authentication IIS", first item returned is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

This does a good cover of the issue.

If you need to apply that to a particular folder, use `location` and `authorization` in web.config as below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: thanks for reply; i already have forms authentication in operatio; rightly or wrongly I wanted to add a 2nd layer of security with a global folder password protect, where the username and password are maintained in the config file - I think.  My experience with php on shared ISP server is that this is very simple to setup & maintain, but now I need to use an inhouse IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same situation. Given that you can't enable forms authentication and basic/windows authentication at the same time in IIS we ended up using [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) and .htaccess files for the digest based authentication and configured the web app itself to use forms authentication. It works well so far. We needed this because of client requirements. I wouldn't really recommend this in practice. It's fairly annoying for users having to log in twice.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am new to asp and iis so might be asking basic questions. My reason for the approach is to hide the login page from automated attack attempts. I have no evidence that this helps, but seems like a good idea. The returning user can always use his browser to cache and passwords so making the process not too much hassle. Are you confirming that I cant acheive what I am after using a web.config file to define a global username and password ?